# Issue in global injector while importing feature effect [Angular 9]

Tags: angular, inheritance, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am facing an issue while importing an effect to feature module.
 *Cannot read property 'get' of undefined* error occurs in global injector.

Following is what I am doing for base service.

`

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AppInjector } from "@app/app-injector.service";
import { StorageService } from "../storage";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class BaseService {
  protected storage: StorageService;
  protected http: HttpClient;

  constructor() {
    this.storage = AppInjector.injector.get(StorageService);
    this.http = AppInjector.injector.get(HttpClient);
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper DI for it.

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AppInjector } from "@app/app-injector.service";
import { StorageService } from "../storage";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class BaseService {
  protected storage: StorageService;
  protected http: HttpClient;

  constructor(appInjector: AppInjector) {
    this.storage = appInjector.injector.get(StorageService);
    this.http = appInjector.injector.get(HttpClient);
  }
}
```